# didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler not called when not attached to xcode iOS 8.0.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

Here's the problem, when the app is attached to xcode, `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` is called.

But when i detach it, it's not called even when the notification is received.

I attached app again (debug->attach to process) & send the notification, `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` called again.

Someone could explain why `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` was not called when i detach it from xcode ?

The app was not force closed. I just open it & put it to background.

Tested in iPhone 5 iOS 8.0.2
APNS Sandbox.

Thank you.

Comment: Remove App, and try again, make sure you are not confusing different signed apps(development,distribution).

Comment: does it matter (removing the app) ? the notification is received, i can tell it by the sound. but the didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler is not called. but if i attach it to xcode, and send the notification again, the method was called.

Comment: Sorry, I understand that you are not getting notification at all.

Comment: If you are getting this situation in bg, have a look on this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776618/didreceiveremotenotification-not-being-called-when-i-tap-on-app-icon-after-recei

Comment: i think i have different case. i'm refering to didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler which is will be called if the the payload have 'content-available':1. the thing is, didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler is called as it should be if i ran the app from xcode, but if i run the it not from xcode, the mthod didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler is not called even the notification is received. i attach the app to xcode with debug->attach to process, send the notification again and the method didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler is called.

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this?